# Select2 dropdown getting hidden

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery

UPDATE: Adding image from console view:
[image: Console View Image]

I am trying to implement Select2 js in my sample page:
Initially I ran into this problem -
[jQuery not a function, $ is not a function on select2.js in doInit method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335893/jquery-not-a-function-is-not-a-function-on-select2-js-in-doinit-method/335924#335924)

but it was solved with rerender method, now I am not gettig $ not found error.
However, after it completes the rerender, the **dropdown just disappears from the page**

Here is my code:

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <!--First Add jQuery and Select2 plugin library from static resource Using ltng:require tag-->
    <ltng:require styles="{! $Resource.Select2 + '/dist/css/select2.min.css'}"
                scripts="{!join(',',
                        $Resource.jQuery ,
                        $Resource.Select2 + '/dist/js/select2.min.js')
                        }" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}"/>
    
    <!-- <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jQuery}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}"/>
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Select2 + '/dist/js/select2.min.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.selectJsLoaded}"/>
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Select2 + '/dist/css/select2.min.css'}" /> -->
    <aura:attribute name="isJSLoaded" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <select id="picklistSelectBox" class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
jsLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('jsLoaded');
    component.set("v.isJSLoaded",true);
},
```

Renderer.js

```
rerender : function(component, helper){
   
    this.superRerender();
    // do custom rerendering here
    var isJSLoaded = component.get("v.isJSLoaded");
    console.log('is JS loaded? changed1-->'+component.get("v.isJSLoaded"));
    if(isJSLoaded){
         $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
        //$(picklistSelectBox).select2();
    }
}
```

I'm baffled by this, any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me and did not disappear

**Aura component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <!--First Add jQuery and Select2 plugin library from static resource Using ltng:require tag-->
    <ltng:require styles="{! $Resource.Select2 + '/dist/css/select2.min.css'}"
                scripts="{!join(',',
                        $Resource.jQuery ,
                        $Resource.Select2 + '/dist/js/select2.min.js')
                        }" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}"/>
    
    <aura:attribute name="isJSLoaded" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <div class="input-group">
      <select id="picklistSelectBox" class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" style="width: 50%">
         <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
         <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

**Controller.js:**

```
({
    jsLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
        });
    }
})
```

It does load the component like below:
[image]

But when i click on the drop-down, i got the below error:

```
aura_prod.js:956 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
throws at https://lightningmonkey-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1625216446000/Select2/select2-4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js:2:8399 TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at s.option (select2.min.js:2)
    at s.append (select2.min.js:2)
    at o.eval (select2.min.js:2)
    at o.e.invoke (select2.min.js:2)
    at o.e.trigger (select2.min.js:2)
    at o.trigger (select2.min.js:2)
    at eval (select2.min.js:2)
    at n.query (select2.min.js:2)
    at o.eval (select2.min.js:2)
    at o.e.invoke (select2.min.js:2)
```

Not sure why would the above error come, probably for another update.